# WPF UI Rendering Confusion, DPI 96 on Two Different Video Cards

Tags: wpf

So I have a question that has me rather confused.  I have a WPF application running on two machines, both machines have the exact same hardware expect for the video cards.  They both have the same monitors as well, just to clarify, and the monitors are both set to have a DPI of 96.

Video Card 1's Specs:
64-bit Memory interface
1GB GDDR3 SDRAM
DirectX 10, OpenGL 3.1

Video Card 2's Specs:
128-bit Memory interface
1GB GDDR3 SDRAM
DirectX 11, OpenGL 4.2

The catch is this, Video Card 1 will run the UI just fine with no issue.  Video Card 2 required me to increase my DPI otherwise the text with blur and sliders will appear jagged.  So does anyone have any insight as to why this may be happening?

**EDIT:** I guess more over my question is that is DPI calculated on the monitor or the video card, and would a higher end video card require a larger DPI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out the issue was down in the styles being used in WPF.  Once I separated the styles from the GUI everything looked okay, I then placed these styles back in one by one and found that the issue was in the style itself.  While this fixes this specific issue, I am still unclear as to why there is a graphical difference between the two video cards.  If someone finds out something that might explain this please let me know.